# Standard deviation question?

Tags: statistics

I know pretty much what the standard deviation is. It's this number that is "kind of" the average distance to the mean. So if I calculate the sd of some data and it turns out to be 0.005, then I know that the most accurate representation of the data would be (the mean) +- 0.005. Now, I don't understand what is meant by something being "1 standard deviation from the mean" or 2, or 3 etc... Please help the king of squirrels out and he may spare you. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an example, taking $\sigma = 0.5$ (standard deviation) and $\mu = 1$ (the mean).  "1 standard deviation from the mean" would require one to take $\mu \pm \sigma$.  So that would mean take $1\pm .5$ to $.5$ and $1.5$.  "Two standard deviations from the mean" would require one to take $\mu \pm 2\sigma$ to obtain $0$ and $2$.  And so on and so forth...

You just obtain an interval to where the mean should be with a given probability according to a stand curve.

Comment: Thank you great sir, I shall spare you.